# Jenkins parallel pipeline does not work as expected

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins declarative pipeline with a parallel stage.
In the parallel stages the config files are changed for every environement and the war package file will be build and deployed.

When I run the parallel pipeline it fails because all the changes are done on the same directory structure and so overwriting all changes from another parallel stage.
How can I make the pipeline parallel proof. So that it runs in his own 'containter' environement?

My parallel stage looks like:

```
stage('Deploy Staging') {
     parallel {
     stage('Deploy APAC') {
     when {
                branch 'develop'
                    }
      steps {
        script {

        configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'bb78f756-623c-412d-8b5d-15756023eb6d', targetLocation: 'src/main/resources/ehcache.xml'), configFile(fileId: 'b48ae55e-5212-4a4f-be6b-e632bb3efe4b', targetLocation: 'src/main/resources/application.properties')]) {
            bat 'mvn clean package  -Dmaven.test.skip=true'
            bat 'move target\\APP-server-*.war APP_APAC.war'
            bat 'cd database && migrate.cmd --env=staging_APAC up'
            powershell 'Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://server/manager/text/deploy?path=/APP_APAC&update=true" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "user", "userpw"))))} -Method PUT -InFile ${PWD}\\APP_APAC.war -ContentType "multipart/form-data" -TimeoutSec 600'
        }

           //build job: 'APP EMEA Staging', parameters: []
                        }
                    }
                }

         stage('Deploy NASA') {
     when {
                branch 'develop'
                    }
      steps {
        script {

        configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'bb78f756-623c-412d-8b5d-15756023eb6d', targetLocation: 'src/main/resources/ehcache.xml'), configFile(fileId: '17086c42-6c7f-4fa0-bdbb-8da4d5f276e1', targetLocation: 'src/main/resources/application.properties')]) {
            bat 'mvn clean package  -Dmaven.test.skip=true'
            bat 'move target\\APP-server-*.war APP_NASA.war'
            bat 'cd database && migrate.cmd --env=staging_NASA up'
            powershell 'Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://server/manager/text/deploy?path=/APP_NASA&update=true" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "user", "userpw"))))} -Method PUT -InFile ${PWD}\\APP_NASA.war -ContentType "multipart/form-data" -TimeoutSec 600'
        }

           //build job: 'APP EMEA Staging', parameters: []
                        }
                    }
                }

         stage('Deploy EMEA') {
     when {
                branch 'develop'
                    }
      steps {
        script {

        configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'bb78f756-623c-412d-8b5d-15756023eb6d', targetLocation: 'src/main/resources/ehcache.xml'), configFile(fileId: 'e02b3492-6f14-4999-8176-f0533ada5bfd', targetLocation: 'src/main/resources/application.properties')]) {
            bat 'mvn clean package  -Dmaven.test.skip=true'
            bat 'move target\\APP-server-*.war APP_EMEA.war'
            bat 'cd database && migrate.cmd --env=staging_EMEA up'
            powershell 'Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://server/manager/text/deploy?path=/APP_EMEA&update=true" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "user", "userpw"))))} -Method PUT -InFile ${PWD}\\APP_EMEA.war -ContentType "multipart/form-data" -TimeoutSec 600'
        }

           //build job: 'APP EMEA Staging', parameters: []
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

So in other words is there a way to copy the current workspace to another one and use that new created workspace in one stage of the parallel stage? If this is possible, then it should fix my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did fix this by copy the full workspace in another workspace for every parallel stage.
When runnning the stages in ws(){} blocks it runs in isolation of the other stages.